# Angular Http Post By Sequence

Tags: angular, typescript

i have this kind of data everytime i post it .it post random in my database how to post it by sequence . want to save first 12 > 13 > 14 > 3

```
let regularBudgetStatus = [
{logicalFrameworkId,logFrameActionStatusReferenceId : 12,remarks : 'ACCEPTED->INCLUSION', actedByEIC },
{logicalFrameworkId,logFrameActionStatusReferenceId : 13,remarks : 'ACCEPTED->APPROPRIATION',actedByEIC },
{logicalFrameworkId,logFrameActionStatusReferenceId : 14, remarks : 'ACCEPTED->RECOMMENDATION', actedByEIC },
{logicalFrameworkId,logFrameActionStatusReferenceId : 3,remarks : 'ACCEPTED->AIP 1ST DRAFT', actedByEIC}
];


this.programservice.saveStatus(item)
.toPromise()
.then(
res => {console.log("success")})
.catch(() => console.log("error"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole array and then save them from your back-end application in sequence.
But if you can't do so, try this:

```
saveNextItem(i: number) {
    this.programservice.saveStatus(item) 
      .toPromise()
      .then(
        res => {
          console.log("success")
          if(i < regularBudgetStatus.length-1) this.saveNextItem(i++);
        })
      .catch(() => console.log("error"));
  }
```

Then just call `saveNextItem(0)` to save the whole array in sequence. Change 'item' variable with regularBudgetStatus[i].logFrameActionStatusReferenceId, I didn't change it for the sake of simplicity.